# Imaginary functions in metric elements

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, complex-numbers

I have solved Einstein's equations for a specific black hole, starting from a general metric with some unknown functions, after solving differential equations I had one imaginary solution. What does it mean when we have an imaginary function in our metric? Is it acceptable at all?
To be clear, the mass of the black hole or any other constant is not imaginary, but for example $g_{tt}$ is an imaginary function.

Comment: Can you give some more information? What does it mean imaginary solution? What will be the physical meaning of an imaginary solution? The mass of the black hole cannot be imaginary.

Comment: No the mass of the black hole is not imaginary, but for example, $g_{tt}$ has some imaginary parts.

Answer (score 1):

The metric components cannot be imaginary, because the spacetime is modelled by a real four-dimensional pseudo-Riemannian manifold. I assume either the calculations are incorrect, or some underlying assumptions were, as obtaining imaginary metric components is akin to finding no solution.

Comment: Ok, that is right. But is it possible that we can remove this imaginary parts? It is in exponential form.

Comment: This has happened to me before. I simplified the solution by appropriately adjusting the integration constants.

Comment: @AminAghababaie if you show your calculations (perhaps in a different question) it'd be much easier to see what's happened.